# Issues with TSQL IN expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

From what I gather about the IN expression, this should work:

```
DECLARE @list varchar(255)

SET @list = '''Item1'',''Item2'''

SELECT
   *
FROM
   Table
WHERE
   Item IN (@list)
```

And it should select those items in @list. The items exist in the table. If I execute the query separately for Item1 and Item2 (Item = Item1, then Item = Item2), those individual queries work. Just not with the IN. Can anyone enlighten me? Figure this is a simple one, just having a rough time finding useful information on this command.

EDIT:

I am currently doing this with dynamic stored procedures where I construct the query in a string and execute. For example, this procedure works:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestSproc]
@list varchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @sql varchar(4000)

SET @sql =
'
SELECT
COUNT(*)
FROM
    Items
WHERE
    Item IN (' + @list + ') '

EXEC (@sql)
```

However, this procedure does not work. It returns 0 rows. If I run it manually for Item1, then Item2, it returns both counts as expected:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestSproc]
    @list varchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    Items
WHERE
    Item IN (@list)
```

I use the same command to call both procedures:

```
EXEC    [dbo].[TestSproc]
    @list = N'''Item1'',''Item2'''
```

I tried to summarize in my original question, but I think it may have thrown people off base. Maybe this will help clear up my issue (barring any dumb typos I made).

Answer (score 3):

The `IN` keyword doesn't operate on a list in a string. It operates on a list of values returned in a query (or on a discrete set of values such as `('Item1','Item2')`, as DaveE mentions in his comment). You could modify `@list` like so:

```
DECALRE @list TABLE (
    value varchar(MAX))

INSERT INTO @list (value)
VALUES ('Item1')

INSERT INTO @list (value)
VALUES ('Item2')

SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Item IN (SELECT value FROM @list)
```

The other option is to create a Table-Valued UDF that takes a comma separated list of values and returns the table. I would suggest against that though as that style of UDF is typically a poor performer.

Comment: Or on a set of discrete values a la ...IN ('Item1', 'Item2')...
 
But definitely not on a string that *looks like* discrete values.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. I'm using lists in the manner folks say doesn't work already, only I am using them in dynamic stored procedures, rather than static SQL. I edited my post to show what I'm talking about. I might have just asked the wrong question, I'm not sure. I thought this was a simple syntax issue.

Comment: In your original code sample, you were using a *single string* that *looked like* a comma-delimited list, not an actual comma delimited list.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to make that work is to use dynamic sql which is a poor idea. Better to take the values and put them in a temp table and join to it.

Comment: Oh, this is apparently what I'm doing. Missed this reply!

Answer (score 1):

The `in()` clause expects a discrete set of values, not a string.  To make this work you will need to dynamically create the entire SQL query as a string and then execute that string.

Try something like this:

```
declare @list varchar(255);
set @list = '''Item1'',''Item2''';

declare @query = varchar(max);
set @query = 'SELECT
   *
FROM
   Table
WHERE
   Item IN (' + @list + ')';

exec(@query);
```

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#CSV

Answer (score 0):

The `@list` you use is a concatenated string which is treated as a single value which should be matched verbatim.

Use this instead:

```
DECLARE @list TABLE (value VARCHAR(255))

INSERT
INTO    @list
VALUES  ('Item1')

INSERT
INTO    @list
VALUES  ('Item2')

SELECT  *
FROM    Table
WHERE   Item IN
        (
        SELECT  value
        FROM    @list
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you have gathered wrongly.

The IN expression does not understand a list of values in form of a string. All it sees is one string. Because that is what you pass in.

You must pass in a an actual list of values, which means one distinct SQL expression per value, separated by actual commas.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table
WHERE  Item IN ('Item1', 'Item2')
```

Alternatively you can do something in the spirit of this.

```
DECLARE @list TABLE (value varchar(50))
INSERT @list VALUES ('Item1')
INSERT @list VALUES ('Item2')

SELECT *
FROM   [Table] t INNER JOIN @list l ON l.value = t.item
```

Answer (score 0):

**NO**, I think you got it all wrong

You should have a look at

- [How to pass a list of values or
  array to SQL Server stored
  procedure?](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/passing_arrays_to_stored_procedures.htm)
- [Convert a string array to tabular
  data in SQL Server](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/datacenter/?p=375)
- [How to pass array of values into SQL
  Server stored procedure using XML](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555266)

Or even

```
--Split
DECLARE @textXML XML
DECLARE @data NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @delimiter NVARCHAR(5)

SELECT  @data = 'A,B,C',
        @delimiter = ','

SELECT    @textXML = CAST('<d>' + REPLACE(@data, @delimiter, '</d><d>') + '</d>' AS XML)
SELECT  T.split.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') AS data
FROM    @textXML.nodes('/d') T(split)
```

Also haev a look at

- [Passing an Array as Parameter to SQL
  Server Procedure](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Array_as_Parameter.aspx)
- [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use a custom table-valued function that can be reused. It comes in handy...especially with parameters to stored procedures and SSRS:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split]
(
  @ItemList NVARCHAR(4000),
  @delimiter CHAR(1)
)
  RETURNS @itemtable TABLE (Item NVARCHAR(50) )

AS

BEGIN
IF @delimiter IS NULL
BEGIN 
set @delimiter = ','
END

DECLARE @tempItemList NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @tempItemList = @ItemList

DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @Item NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @tempItemList = REPLACE (@tempItemList, @delimiter + ' ', @delimiter)
SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)

WHILE (LEN(@tempItemList) > 0)
BEGIN
IF @i = 0
SET @Item = @tempItemList
ELSE
SET @Item = LEFT(@tempItemList, @i - 1)

INSERT INTO @itemtable(Item) VALUES(@Item)

IF @i = 0
SET @tempItemList = ''
ELSE
SET @tempItemList = RIGHT(@tempItemList, LEN(@tempItemList) - @i)

SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)
END
RETURN
END
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
DECLARE @list varchar(255)     

SET @list = '''Item1'',''Item2'''     

SELECT     *     
FROM     Table     
WHERE  Item IN (select * from dbo.fn_Split(@list,null))  //Right HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the best source:

http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html

create a split function, and use it like:

```
SELECT
    *
    FROM YourTable  y
    INNER JOIN dbo.splitFunction(@Parameter) s ON y.ID=s.Value
```

[I prefer the number table approach](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#tblnum)

For this method to work, you need to do this one time table setup:

```
SELECT TOP 10000 IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS Number
    INTO Numbers
    FROM sys.objects s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2
ALTER TABLE Numbers ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Numbers PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Number)
```

Once the Numbers table is set up, create this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_ListToTable]
(
     @SplitOn  char(1)      --REQUIRED, the character to split the @List string on
    ,@List     varchar(8000)--REQUIRED, the list to split apart
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(

    ----------------
    --SINGLE QUERY-- --this will not return empty rows
    ----------------
    SELECT
        ListValue
        FROM (SELECT
                  LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(List2, number+1, CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, List2, number+1)-number - 1))) AS ListValue
                  FROM (
                           SELECT @SplitOn + @List + @SplitOn AS List2
                       ) AS dt
                      INNER JOIN Numbers n ON n.Number < LEN(dt.List2)
                  WHERE SUBSTRING(List2, number, 1) = @SplitOn
             ) dt2
        WHERE ListValue IS NOT NULL AND ListValue!=''

);
GO
```

You can now easily split a CSV string into a table and join on it:

```
select * from dbo.FN_ListToTable(',','1,2,3,,,4,5,6777,,,')
```

OUTPUT:

```
ListValue
-----------------------
1
2
3
4
5
6777

(6 row(s) affected)
```

Your can pass in a CSV string into a procedure and process only rows for the given IDs:

```
SELECT
    y.*
    FROM YourTable y
        INNER JOIN dbo.FN_ListToTable(',',@GivenCSV) s ON y.ID=s.ListValue
```

**This will use an index on y.ID**